# Spinrad essays on science fiction stimulating technology

Tags: technology, history-of

Science fiction writer Norman Spinrad sometimes reviews books in Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine. Spinrad will use these book reviews as an excuse to jump on a soap box and deliver his own opinion pieces.

There were several interesting book reviews/essays where Sprinrad opined science fiction spurs progress in engineering and technology. If I remember right, he thought submarines, spaceships as well as some communication and computer innovations were inspired by science fiction.

Is anyone familiar with these essays? I am hoping to find the issues of Asimov's that carried them. Or better yet, find the essays online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the essays have been collected in the book [*Science Fiction in the Real World*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/633203.Science_Fiction_in_the_Real_World). Goodreads' description says:

> In these 13 essays, Spinrad urges science fiction as a genre to reach its potential. He divides the essays—**new works written specifically for this book combined with those that appeared in Isaac Asimov’s Science Fiction Magazine**—into five sections: "Literature and Genre: A Critical Overview," in which Spinrad establishes his critical standards; "Alternate Media: Visual Translations," a discussion of comic books and books made into movies; "Modes of Content: Hard SF, Cyberpunk, and the Space Visionaries"; "Psychopolitics and Science Fiction: Heroes—True and Otherwise"; and "Masters of the Form: Careers in Profile," discussions of Sturgeon, Vonnegut, Ballard, and Dick.

In particular the following essays appeared on *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, as stated at the beginning of the book (see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=EvCsY3IEJ14C&pg=PA217&lpg=PA217&dq=science%20fiction%20in%20the%20real%20world&source=bl&ots=P12xCzO7fd&sig=kHrdQqK_c3HWaPxaeQTwGaq2SYw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMhtWEgfrJAhUH9w4KHS0KBIUQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false), pg. iv):

- 1985: [*Inside, Outside*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?982387) (Jul), [*Books into Movies*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?983094) (Nov);
- 1986: [*Must there be war?*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?983468) (Jan), [*The neuromantics*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?983657) (May), [*Critical Standards*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?983860) (Sep), [*Science Fiction versus Sci-fi*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?984178) (Dec);
- 1987: [*Sturgeon, Vonnegut and Trout*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?984494) (Apr), [*Dreams of Space*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?984860) (Oct);
- 1988: [*Emperor of Everything*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?668265) (Jan), [*The Hard Stuff*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?985271) (Mar), [*The Strange Case of J.G. Ballard*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?985333) (Jun), [*The Graphic Novel*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?985986) (Dec).

For the full list of Spinrad's essays go to the Internet Science Fiction Database's page about him [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1019). The most part of his essays published on *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine* are listed under the category *On Books*. Also, to browse the full issues index head [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?20321). Each issue and article's page has a link to buy the item.